# Issue when updating composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I am getting an issue when trying to create controllers in Laravel so decided to try and update composer and am getting the following issues when running `composer update`;

```
[BadMethodCallException]            
  Call to undefined method [package]  


Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error


  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:       


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--] [<packages>]...
```

The error I get when trying to create a new controller;

```
  [BadMethodCallException]            
  Call to undefined method [package]
```

So I believe the 2 to be connected however I may be incorrect.

Output of composer update -vvv

```
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Executing command (/Users/kieran/Sites/Dev/laravel): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (/Users/kieran/Sites/Dev/laravel): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/Users/kieran/Sites/Dev/laravel): hg branch
Executing command (/Users/kieran/Sites/Dev/laravel): svn info --xml
Reading /Users/kieran/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /Users/kieran/.composer/composer.json
> pre-update-cmd: php artisan clear-compiled
Executing command (CWD): php artisan clear-compiled


  [BadMethodCallException]            
  Call to undefined method [package]  


Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error


  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:       


Exception trace:
 () at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:196
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:94
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchScript() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:196
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:159
 Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:259
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:840
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:192
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:167
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:123
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:98
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/bin/composer:43
 require() at /usr/local/bin/composer:25

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Comment: Is this while upgrading Laravel? Or making a config change?

Comment: No I literally went to create a controller got the error so looked online and people said to try updating composer, I was then greeted by the other message.

Comment: Would you post your config/app.php and composer.json to somewhere?

Comment: Also, please provide the output of `php artisan list`

Comment: Sorry for multiple comments, can only edit for so long, also please post the output of `composer update -vvv`

Comment: php artisan list returns the same error, I have updated the post to include composer update -vvv

Comment: One last thing, does mcrypt show up if you run `php -m`?

Comment: install/enable mcrypt, should fix your issue

Comment: I have installed mcrypt and this didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `undefined method [package]` can often be from trying to use a package that was built for Laravel 4 in Laravel 5.

The `package` method was removed from Service Providers in Laravel 5+.

Check any package service providers for a call to the `package` method on the provider.

Comment: I cannot see anywhere where this is being used? What files would it be located in?

Comment: if this is the issue it would be in one of the service providers. you could search your project for `->package(` if you needed to.

Comment: The laptop has just been rescued from going out the window, this worked perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this commands.Usually it helps me sometimes when my php artisan or composer command throws and error..

```
composer dump-autoload
```

also

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tried both and neither worked the dump-autoload ran and didn't resolve and the cache:clear didn't run due to the same issue.